# how to start with Withings API in grails project

Tags: api, grails, withings

I went through some of the documents of the Withings API [reference url](http://www.withings.com/en/api) and I registered my application [here](http://www.withings.com/en/api/oauthguide#registration), even though I don't got any basic idea on how to start with this API like,

1. how to find user's detail?
2. who will approve our application and how the user will allow us to access their data? like a lot, please help me in this.